# What is SBT global Scope?

Tags: sbt

I have red the Doc on the different Scopes in SBT, **but I have trouble being comfortable with the global scope Axis. I just don't understand in simple terms what does it correspond to?**

Can someone provided a more elaborated but simpler explanation of the Global Scope than what in on the current Doc.

> My first guess is that it is something encompassing the project scope.
>   Something like ***for all project.***

I would appreciate if one could take a bit of time to explain it.

Many thanks,

M